# String encoding/decoding (PHP-Android)

Tags: php, android, encoding, decoding

in my Android app I use this method:

```
URLDecoder.decode(this.name,"UTF-8")
```

It decodes the name sent from my server side, where, in PHP, I use:

```
urlencode($name);
```

Apparently, this is not working. I want the name to show with national characters. Could you help me how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are doing it right. Let's make some test:
Initial string: $name = "test-€$ț" ; 
Encoded string with urlencode($name): test-%E2%82%AC%24%C8%9B ; 
Decoded string with URLDecoder.decode(name, "UTF-8"): test-€$ț

Comment: Finally, the problem was solved using an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server side try:

```
urlencode(utf8_encode($name));
```